# Notice: Undefined index: post_title error

Tags: php, functions, debug, wp-debug

This is my code:

```
function insert_custom_post_test($args){    
    $args['post_content'] = '';
    $args['post_status']  =   'publish';

    if($args['post_title'] == 'test_title'){
        // Code
    } else {
        // Code
    }
}
```

Wordpress debug given me an error in $args['post_title'] don't know why!

I think that because I don't define $args but it's a function and I get the args from the function.

NOTE: I try to add $args = array(); to define $args but that's doesn't solve the problem.

how can solve this?

Comment: This  tells me that the `$args` Array variable does not have an index of `post_title` so it really depends on what you're passing to this function. Additionally, you could check if it [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Comment: This question isn't related to WordPress. It's a basic PHP question.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? Undefined index?

Comment: var_dump $args and what does it give ?